# How to hide the "Scroll down" icon and text behind the mobile navbar?

Tags: reactjs, mobile, responsive-design, tailwind-css, web-frontend

z-index issue with React JS and Tailwind CSS. I cannot hide the icon and the text behind the mobile navbar when I open it. It just pops up over the mobile menu. I wrote Mobile Navbar icon functions in Navbar.js and Scroll Down items in Home.js (Seperate files)

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YOw0Y.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJT5n.png)

I tried position absolute with z-index (absolute z-3), but I couldn't manage to solve the issue.

Comment: Can you share some code? I used to get a lot of these mistakes and it all comes to Z-Index

Comment: Sure!

Home.js

<div className="mt-24 flex justify-center flex-col items-center text-white lg:hidden relative z-1 ">
                <div><TfiArrowCircleDown className="animate-bounce" size="55" /></div><br />
                <p className="text-white animate-pulse">Scroll down</p>
            </div>

Comment: Body.js

<div className={`${close ? "block" : "hidden"} bg-[#101E2A] flex text-2xl h-[730px] w-screen absolute top-0 z-3`}>
            <div><RiCloseFill onClick={handleClose} className="absolute left-[85%] top-2 text-5xl" /></div>
                <ul className="shadow w-full mt-14">
                {Links.map((item, key) => (
                <li className="py-2 w-min ml-10 hover:text-cyan-600 mt-8" key={key}><a href={item.link}>{item.name}</a></li>
            ))}
            </ul>
        </div>

Comment: I meant a Codesandbox, So me and others can interact with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to hide it, you can use the visibillity property and set it to hidden (CSS)

Comment: It worked! Now I realised my mistake, thanks sir!

Comment: I'm glad to hear that, would you put the answer on approved, I know it sounds nitpicky but I'm trying to get some reputation to finally comment under posts :)